# Editor doesn't want to display a code on the web-page

Tags: html, browser, editor

[image]

So here is the problem:

**No matter** what i do in the editor , it's just not displaying the code on the web-page. I've tried everything(apparently not) to solve this but my attempts went in vain. Any suggestions? Tell me , if it's not clear.
I don't understand why it is not working. The extension of the file is correct *blablabla.html*. There's no error in the code of the web-page. Browser simply doesn't want to respond on any changes in the editor.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. When asking a question, you will get much better answers if you provide code. Add what you have tried so far. Also please check [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Did you saved the file? I see a dot in the tab of your editor, wich means something is not saved. In your editor crtl + s on windows and cmd + s on mac

Comment: Omg,i'm such an idiot .You're a genius :D  thx, solved.

Comment: Haha You're welcome :)